# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 229,Token in error = Interactive ]

Tags: c#

When try to execute get error

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Finalresult (section_name,examid,userid,solveqty,dateexam,totalqty) values('" + section + "','" + examis + "','" + UserId + "','" + newId + "','" + DateTime.Now + "'"+
                ",'(Select count(SubQno) from Question where Section_name='" + section + "')')";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

get error at line  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); error message is There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 229,Token in error = Interactive ]

Comment: Not directly related, but your code would be a lot cleaner and safer if you used command parameters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Print the command and look at the generated SQL, probably missing `'` around a string value. Also, using command parameters would solve this and be more secure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the single quotes around your nested select.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Finalresult (section_name,examid,userid,solveqty,dateexam,totalqty) values('" + section + "','" + examis + "','" + UserId + "','" + newId + "','" + DateTime.Now + "',(Select count(SubQno) from Question where Section_name='" + section + "'))";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You should not be doing it this way anyway, you should use [command parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build up your query.

e.g.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Finalresult (section_name,examid,userid,solveqty,dateexam,totalqty) values(@section, @exam, @user, @solve, @date, (Select count(SubQno) from Question where Section_name=@section))";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", section);
```